# Postgresql User defined Functions creation date or modified date

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to check when a user-defined function is created or altered in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-matrix.html)

```
create or replace function log_create() 
  returns event_trigger 
as 
$$
declare 
 l_name text;
begin
   select object_identity
     into l_name
   from pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands();
   raise notice 'Function %s created', l_name;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;


create event trigger event_trigger_log_create
  on ddl_command_end
  when tag IN ('CREATE FUNCTION', 'ALTER FUNCTION')
  execute procedure log_create();
```

But unless you create an event trigger in advance to log the creation of functions, there is no way to tell when a function was created.